# how to solve the error at the stopword filtering stage, with TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I have problems running my program, where at the stopwords-filtering stage the output generated is an error as shown in the following code.
This is my code input:

```
#filter stopwords 
def stopword_removal(comment):
  filtering = stopwords.words('english')
  x = []
  data = [] 
  def myFunc(x):
    if x in filtering:
      return False 
    else:
      return True
  fit = filter(myFunc, comment)
  for x in fit:
    data.append(x)
  return data 
df['04'] = df['03'].apply(stopword_removal)
df.sort_values("04", inplace = True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset = "04", keep = 'first', inplace = True)
df
```

This is my code output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-40f0625ed77c> in <module>()
     13     data.append(x)
     14   return data
---> 15 df['04'] = df['03'].apply(stopword_removal)
     16 df.sort_values("04", inplace = True)
     17 df.drop_duplicates(subset = "04", keep = 'first', inplace = True)

4 frames
<ipython-input-22-40f0625ed77c> in stopword_removal(comment)
      9     else:
     10       return True
---> 11   fit = filter(myFunc, comment)
     12   for x in fit:
     13     data.append(x)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: That means comment is None

Answer (score 0):

python [filter builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) requires an iterable to apply something. The error message

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Means you're trying to apply function "myFunc" to something on which you cannot iterate, like "None".
So, it just means that "comment" variable happens to be None in some cases.

To confirm, you may add the following line at the top of your function "stopword_removal":

```
assert comment is not None
```

The code should raise an AssertionError on this line.

Then, you need to assess if "comment" variable has valid reasons to be None in certain circumstances, in which case you remove the assert line and just return from the function without further processing, or investigate why it's None while it shouldn't be, and fix the corresponding code.